# ReferenceError: google is not defined After Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, angular6

I am using Google Places API in my website for autosuggestion purpose, In First go It Works fine but when i refreshes the page on particular angular component it shows error that

`ReferenceError: google is not defined`

i have searched number of website but none of solution worked i have tried adding `async` and `defer` in script tag in `index.html` but doesn't works

**register.component.ts**

```
declare var google: any;
export class RegisterComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   constructor() { }
   ngAfterViewInit() {
      const input = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('googlePlaces');
      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, { types: ['geocode'] });
      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
       this.place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      })
   }
}
```

**register.component.html**

```
<input id="googlePlaces" type="text" class="input-custom" formControlName="location" placeholder="Enter Place">
```

and I have added script in main `index.html` file with valid API key which seems to be okay as it works in first go

Comment: You try to use google before it is load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the proper way to initialize google map in angular

Look at this code and you'll find your happiness on Google :)

```
this._mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocompleteInput'), {});
      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
          const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          ...
       });
     ...
   });
```

mapsAPILoader and ngZone must be added into the constructor

```
 constructor(
      private _mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
      private _ngZone: NgZone) { }
```

Don't hesitate to vote if it helps ;)

Comment: Using @agm/core which version of google map are you trying to use ?

Comment: Actually i was importing google maps api through cdn script file provided by google as we use it in javascript but now i installed agm/core and it worked **Thnx**

Comment: You could make it work, but you'll have to reimplement this kind of await function using document ready or angular events / promises

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
let listen; 
    this._mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      let autocomplete = new  google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocompleteInput'), {});
      listen = google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
        this._ngZone.run(() => {
          const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          ...
       });
     ...
   });
...
        google.maps.event.removeListener(listen); // then you can reload autocomplete without problens
```